# Facebook login problems

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, ios-app

I am having trouble logging in on my computer to Stack Exchange (I'm using my iPhone right now). When I try to log in with Facebook (I think that's what I logged in with), it goes to the home page but does not log in.

Has this happened before, and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you describe the steps you're taking to log in and what you're seeing at each step?

Comment: @AnnaLear Well, there's not much to it. I'm clicking "log in", and once the page loads, clicking the log in with Facebook button. Then it's sending me directly to the home page without logging me in.

Comment: Are you already logged in to Facebook on your phone?

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, that is the case.

Comment: Two more questions: are you using the mobile UI or the desktop version? And is this in Safari or Chrome?

Comment: For question 1 - I'm using the Stack Exchange app. On my computer I'm using the desktop version. For question 2 - Chrome. @AnnaLear

Comment: Oh. I'm not gonna be much help with the app beyond trying to reproduce this. Gonna have to grab someone on the mobile team. My bad - I should've asked earlier.

Comment: @AnnaLear Alright, sorry about that.

Comment: When you say home page, what do you mean exactly? Are you just going right back to the login screen as if you hadn't hit login at all?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I was sent to https://stackexchange.com after login.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi It was a glitch, I went to an individual site (PPCG) that I had joined on my phone and it logged me in. Just did that now.

Comment: Huh, thanks for reporting back. Still going to continue looking into this to figure out what caused the glitch.